# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: mysql

I cannot insert user data into my database. Problem occurs in execute() function:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

My code:

```php
$sql ="INSERT INTO tbl_user(name,username,email,password) VALUES(:name,:username,:email,:password)";

$q = $this->db->pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->bindValue(':name',$name);
$q->bindValue(':username',$username);
$q->bindValue(':email',$email);
$q->bindValue(':password',$password);

$result = $q->execute();
```

Comment: `No database selected`.  Hmmm.  How did you connect?  Something like this: `$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1'; $myPDO = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password');`?  In other words, *DID YOU SPECIFY AN INITIAL DATABASE*?

Answer (score 0):

First please make sure your connection string is correct and you are successfully connected.

If the error is still there try

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO DATABASE_NAME.tbl_user(name,username,email,password) VALUES(:name,:username,:email,:password)";
```